# Created a python program to estimate travel time and having an error

Tags: python

I have got everything working but for some reason when i put 500 for miles and 80 for mph it says invalid input.

Here is my code.

```
import time
import datetime

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

ch='y'
print("Arrival Time Estimator\n\n")
while ch!='n':
    try:
        est_date_dept = input('Estimated date of departure (YYYY-MM-DD):')
        est_time_dept = input('Estimated time of departure (HH:MM AM/PM):')
        dist = int(input('Enter Miles:'))
        speed = int(input('Enter miles per hour:'))
        travel_time = int(dist)/speed
        t=timedelta(hours=travel_time)
        t=str(t)
        t=t.split(':')
        if t[2] > '00':
          t[1]=int(t[1])+1
          travel_time+=0.01
          time = datetime.strptime(est_time_dept, "%I:%M %p")
          est_time_dept = datetime.strftime(time, "%H:%M")
          est_date_dept = est_date_dept+" "+est_time_dept
          arr_date_time = datetime.strptime(est_date_dept, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
          arr_date_time += timedelta(hours=travel_time)
          est_arr = arr_date_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")
          est_arr=str(est_arr)
        est_arr=est_arr.split()
        print ('\n\nEstimated travel time')
        print ('Hours:',t[0],'\nMinutes:', t[1])
        print ('Estimated date of arrival:',est_arr[0])
        print ('Estimated time of arrival:', est_arr[1], est_arr[2])
        ch = input('\nContinue? (y/n):')
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
        ch = input("\nContinue? (y/n):")
```

The output I get is
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slKej.png)

Comment: If you want to know what's going wrong, don't use a bare `except:` that throws that information away. Either remove the `try:/except:` (at least temporarily, for debugging), or change it to `except Exception as e:` and `print(f"Invalid input: {e!r}")` or something that includes the error message.

Comment: If you replace `except` with `except Exception as e:` and then `print ("Invalid input {}".format(e))` you see `invalid syntax` and other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know what's going wrong, don't use a bare `except:` that throws that information away.

Either remove the `try:`/`except:` (at least temporarily, for debugging), or change it to `except Exception as e:` and then `print(f"Invalid input: {e!r}")`, or something that includes the error message.

---

For your inputs, if the date or time is invalid, the actual exception is something like this:

```
ValueError("time data '19:23 AM' does not match format '%I:%M %p'")
```

In that case, the error message is correct—the input is invalid. It's not all that *useful*, because you're not giving the user any idea which of their four inputs is invalid, or why, but it is correct.

But if they're both valid, the error is this:

```
NameError("name 'est_arr' is not defined")
```

And in that case, calling the input invalid is wrong.

---

Why do you get this? Well, let's work it through:

```
travel_time = int(dist)/speed # int(500)/80 = 6.25
t=timedelta(hours=travel_time) # timedelta with 6:15:00
t=str(t) # the string '6:15:00'
t=t.split(':') # the list ['6', '15', '00']
if t[2] > '00': # not true, because '00' is not > '00'
# if body skipped
est_arr=est_arr.split() # oops, NameError
```

You never assign anything to `est_arr` if the time is an exact number of minutes (with no seconds left over).

So, when you try to use `est_arr`, you get a `NameError` telling you that you never assigned anything to that name.

How can you fix this? Well, I don't know what you were trying to do there. Why did you put that `if` there in the first place? What did you want to happen when it wasn't true? I can't think of any good reason for that, but presumably you had one in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you do a textual comparison on values, but seem to assume that the results will be based on their integer appearance.  As a result, you do not enter the `if t[2]` block, and `est_arr` isn't defined.  You need to handle this case *and* repair the logic that led you there.

Comment: The textual comparison isn't a problem. The seconds part of `t` is a two-digit string, which is `> '00'` or not depending on whether there are any leftover seconds or not in the timedelta. The problem is that the logic the OP has correctly implemented is incorrect logic.